# SQL Server - Drop all triggers from table where trigger names are unknown

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am using SignalR which automatically creates triggers, with random names, on a database table.

Is there a way of using T-SQL script to DROP all triggers from a specific table without dropping the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use dynamic SQL and [sys.triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-triggers-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) system table:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(FORMATMESSAGE(N'DROP TRIGGER %s.%s;'
                                      ,QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id))
                                      ,QUOTENAME(t.name))
                        ,NCHAR(13))
FROM sys.triggers AS t
WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0
  AND t.parent_id = OBJECT_ID('table_name');

PRINT @sql;  -- debug
--EXEC(@sql);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3fd2be3c43121475aa8b2d8b709a4d3c)**

---

## EDIT:

SQL Server 2012 version:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @sql += FORMATMESSAGE(N'DROP TRIGGER %s.%s;'
                                      ,QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id))
                                      ,QUOTENAME(t.name))
                        + NCHAR(13)
FROM sys.triggers AS t
WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0
  AND t.parent_id = OBJECT_ID('t');

PRINT @sql;  -- debug
--EXEC(@sql);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=79ad5acc915597ba197f3f0b918862dc)**

Comment: This looks to be the correct answer, although my SQL Server instance (Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64)) does not seem to support STRING_AGG. Apologies for not mentioning SQL Server version. Would you know an approach that would work in SQL Server 2014?

Comment: @phicon Then you need to change the code to use `@sql += DROP ...`